# Linear and circular convolution in Python

Tags: python, numpy, fft, convolution, ifft

I'm trying to perform linear convolutions in Python by comparing the results from FFTs and convolution functions.

Python's [`scipy.signal.fftconvolve`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.fftconvolve.html) automatically does the necessary zero padding. If we do the calculation using only FFTs, we add a length of zeros after our input signal. Is there a way to trim the output array of the FFT result? (The `fftconvolve` has a `mode='same'` option where the output array is the same size as the input.)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft,ifft
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tf = 50
ti = -tf
N = 2**10
t = np.linspace(ti,tf,N)
T = (tf-ti)/N

x = np.exp(-4*t**2)*np.cos(t)
y = (t-2)/((t-2)**2+3**2)

z1 = ifft(fft(x,len(x)+len(y)-1)*fft(y,len(x)+len(y)-1)) # need zero-padding
z2 = fftconvolve(x,y,mode='same') # automatic zero-padding

plt.figure(0)
plt.plot(t,z2)
#plt.figure(1)
#plt.plot(t,z1)
```

**Note:** Another issue is if we change the outputs to:

```
z1 = ifft(fft(x,len(x)+len(y)-1)*fft(y,len(x)+len(y)-1))*T
z2 = fftconvolve(x,y)*T
```

(where `T` is a normalisation constant) then plot either `z1` or `z2`, we get strange boundary effects:

[image]

This effect is explained in [this DSP post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1933/how-to-remove-the-boundary-effects-arising-due-to-zero-padding-in-scipy-numpy-ff), but I'm not sure how to apply the solutions to my system.

Comment: For what reason do you do the zero padding?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Python does circular convolution, so we need the zero padding to do a linear convolution. See also: http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/741/why-should-i-zero-pad-a-signal-before-taking-the-fourier-transform

Comment: @MedullaOblongata I can't give you a solution to your problem, but when I used convolution product during my Astrophysics internship, I used astropy and his convolve function : http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/convolution/